# Is a Finite Increasing Chain of Closed Sets the Closure of the Union of the Interiors of the Relative Complements?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose there are closed subsets $X=:F_{k}\supseteq F_{k-1}\supseteq\cdots\supseteq F_{1}\supseteq F_{0}:=\emptyset$. Is it true that

> $\overline{\bigcup_{j=1}^{k}\operatorname{Int}(F_{j}\setminus F_{j-1})}=X$?

If $k=1$, the result is trivial. For $k>1$, we have
$$
\overline{\bigcup_{j=1}^{k}\operatorname{Int}(F_{j}\setminus F_{j-1})}=\overline{\operatorname{Int}(X\setminus F_{k-1})}\cup\overline{\bigcup_{j=1}^{k-1}\operatorname{Int}(F_{j}\setminus F_{j-1})}=\overline{X\setminus F_{k-1}}\cup\overline{\bigcup_{j=1}^{k-1}\operatorname{Int}(F_{j}\setminus F_{j-1})}.
$$

When $k=2$, the RHS simplifies to
$$
\overline{X\setminus F_{1}}\cup\overline{\operatorname{Int}(F_{1})}=\overline{X\setminus\operatorname{bd}(F_{1})}=X.
$$

I'm not sure if it's possible to carry out a similar reduction when $k>2$; or, if this result is indeed true. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $j=1,\dots, k$ put $X_j=\operatorname{bd} (F_j\setminus F_{j-1})=\overline{F_j\setminus F_{j-1}}\setminus \operatorname{Int} (F_j\setminus F_{j-1})$. It is easy to check that each $X_j$ is nowhere dense in $X$, $X\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^k X_j$ is dense in $X$. Let $U$ be a nonempty open subset of $X$. Then $U’=U\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^k X_j$ is also a nonempty open subset of $X$. Pick an arbitrary point $x$ of $U’$ and the smallest $j$ such that $x\in F_j$. Then $x\in (F_j\setminus F_{j-1})\setminus \operatorname{bd} (F_j\setminus F_{j-1})\subset \operatorname{Int} (F_j\setminus F_{j-1})$. Thus $$x\in U’\cap \operatorname{Int} (F_j\setminus F_{j-1})\subset U\cap \bigcup_{j=1}^k\operatorname{Int} (F_j\setminus F_{j-1}).$$